# What is the proper way to close a session using neo4j-javascript-driver?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, neo4j-driver

Right now I am executing [writeTransactions](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/sessions-transactions/#driver-transactions-transaction-functions) closing the neo4j driver session as suggested by the documentation.

However, I haven't found how to handle the `session.close()` when there is an error. This might be leading to all the connections of the pool never closing and I'm receiving a lot of errors like this after some days that the application is up:

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5725): 
Neo4jError: Connection acquisition timed out in 60000 ms.
```

This is the driver configuration:

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
  process.env.NEO4J_URI,
  neo4j.auth.basic(process.env.NEO4J_USER, process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD),
  {
    maxConnectionLifetime: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    maxConnectionPoolSize: 300,
    encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_ON",
    trust: "TRUST_CUSTOM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES",
    trustedCertificates: [process.env.NEO4J_TRUSTED_CERTS],
    logging: {
      level: 'debug',
      logger: (level, message) => console.log('+++' + level + ' ' + message)
    }
  }
);
```

These are the 2 ways I'm using the driver with transactions:

**1. Using async/await and catch**

```
const neo4jsession = driver.session();

var result = await neo4jsession.writeTransaction(tx =>
  tx.run("Cypher Query")
).catch(err => {
  try {
    neo4jsession.close();
  } finally {
    reject(err);
  }
});

neo4jsession.close();

// Do something with result if not undefined
```

**2. Using then/catch**

```
const neo4jsession = driver.session();

var result = neo4jsession.writeTransaction(tx =>
  tx.run("Cypher Query")
);

result.then(items => {
  neo4jsession.close();
  // do something with items
}).catch(error => {
  try {
    neo4jsession.close();
  } finally {
    reject(error);
  }
});
```

Am I correctly closing the sessions in both cases? If not, what's the proper way of closing the session for both cases?

Please help, this has been a headache for days =(

Answer (score 3):

For your first case, you can do something easier :

```
const neo4jsession = driver.session();
try {
  let result = await neo4jsession.writeTransaction(tx =>   tx.run("Cypher Query") )
} 
catch( err } {
  reject(err);
}
finally {
  neo4jsession.close();
}
```

And you can use the same pattern for the second case.

Comment: Thanks, this can help for my first case. However, the code I'm working with is quite extensive and refactoring all the second cases to use the same pattern as the first case is not exactly easy. That's why I asked for both cases separately.